# Combining 2 tables and getting the last record per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables and I'm trying to combine them, while removing duplicate entries, I only want to get the last submitted date per month.

[image: Tables]

[image: Field]

unfortunately I was not able to get this working

```
a.[Region],
a.[Country],
a.[site],
a.[Account Type],
q.[month], 
q.[account],
q.[metric],
q.[Goal],
q.[Unit],
q.[Actual],
q.[Waived],
q.[Weight],
q.[Achieved],
q.[SubmittedDateTime]

from [accountTable] a right join [scoreTable] q, (select
max(q.[SubmittedDateTime]) as max_date
group by q.[Month])  on a.[account] = q.[account]
```

Answer (score 1):

This following script will return you Account/Year/Month wise Last submitted date. I have added Account in consideration as you Joined both table. If only Month wise last submitted is required, I am confused why you need to join tables as Month wise results can be retrieve only from scoreTable!

```
SELECT a.[account],
YEAR(SubmittedDateTime),
MONTH(SubmittedDateTime),
MAX(SubmittedDateTime) 
FROM [accountTable] a 
INNER JOIN [scoreTable] q
    ON a.[account] = q.[account]
GROUP BY .[account],
YEAR(SubmittedDateTime),
MONTH(SubmittedDateTime)
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to SQL, what's happening is that these data is connected to Google Data Studio, When data studio captures it, the score is adding up. That's why we want to get only the last submitted date.

There's also an instance wherein they want us to update their score from months ago. What we are doing is to reupload the scores to our database, The only problem is data studio is summing up their scores.

Comment: @kahel You can add your expected data with the question which will help. Also please avoid image and add tabular data for all cased which is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows within each month and just choose the last one:

```
select s.*, a.region, a.country, a.site
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.account, year(s.submitteddatetime), month(s.submitteddatetime)
                                order by submitteddatetime desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from scoreTable s
     ) s join
     accountTable a
     on a.account = s.account
where s.seqnum = 1;
```